# hii i'm trying to learn pdo over mysqli so i want to know how i can change my existing code using store procedure

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo

first i'm creating functions which call store procedure so i want to do the same with pdo i have tried different ways searched a lot but couldnt find  a proper solution
my function.php

```
<?php
function AddWords($word,$meaning,$synonym,$antonym){
include("conn.php");
$result=mysqli_query($conn,"CALL AddWords('$word','$meaning','$synonym','$antonym')");
//echo "CALL AddWords('$word','$meaning','$synonym','$antonym')";
return $result;
}
function GetWords($word){
    include("conn.php");
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,"CALL GetWords('$word')");
    return $result;
}
function GetAdminWords(){
    include("conn.php");
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,"CALL GetAdminWords()");
    return $result;
}
function GetWordsByID($id){
    include("conn.php");
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,"CALL GetWordsById($id)");
    return $result;
}
function Deletewords($id){
    include("conn.php");
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,"CAll DeleteWords($id)");
    return $result;
}
function UpdateWords($word,$meaning,$synonym,$antonym,$id){
    include("conn.php");
$result=mysqli_query($conn,"CALL UpdateWords('$word','$meaning','$synonym','$antonym',$id)");
//echo "CALL UpdateWords('$word','$meaning','$synonym','$antonym',$id)";
return $result;
}
function SortContent(){
    include("conn.php");
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,"CALL SortContent()");
    return $result;
}
function SortContent2(){
    include("conn.php");
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,"CALL SortContent2()");
    return $result;
}
?>
```

then call this function in main file where i'm using mysqli_escape_string
which i want to achieve in pdo
my main file

```
<?php
include("conn.php");
include("function.php");
if(isset($_POST['btn_submit'])){
    $word=$_POST['word'];
    $meaning=$_POST['meaning'];
    $antonym=$_POST['antonym'];
    $synonym=$_POST['synonym'];
    if(!isset($_GET['id1'])){
    $result=AddWords(mysqli_escape_string($conn,$word),mysqli_escape_string($conn,$meaning),mysqli_escape_string($conn,$synonym),mysqli_escape_string($conn,$antonym));

    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Saved Successfully!!')</script>";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location='view.php'</script>";  

}
    if(isset($_GET['id1'])){
        //echo $_GET['id1'];
        $id=$_GET['id1'];
        $result=UpdateWords(mysqli_escape_string($conn,$word),mysqli_escape_string($conn,$meaning),mysqli_escape_string($conn,$synonym),mysqli_escape_string($conn,$antonym),$id,$conn);

        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Saved Successfully!!')</script>";
         echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location='view.php'</script>";       
    }

}
?>
```

in my code i'm mostly using mysqli_escape_string

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_GET['id1'])){
        $id=$_GET['id1'];
        $result=GetWordsById(mysqli_escape_string($conn,$id));
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
            $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        $word=$row['word'];
        $meaning=$row['meaning'];
        $synonym=$row['synonym'];
        $antonym=$row['antonym'];


        }
    ?>
    <form method="post">
<div class="container container-fluid">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
        <label for="inputdefault">Add Word</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="inputdefault" type="text" name="word" value="<?php if(isset($word)){echo $word;}?>">
        <label for="inputdefault">Add Meaning</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="inputdefault" type="text" name="meaning" value="<?php if(isset($meaning)){echo $meaning;}?>">
        <label for="inputdefault">Add Synonym</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="inputdefault" type="text" name="synonym" value="<?php if(isset($synonym)){echo $synonym;}?>">
        <label for="inputdefault">Add Antonym</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="inputdefault" type="text" name="antonym" value="<?php if(isset($antonym)){echo $antonym;}?>"><br>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="btn_submit" >Submit</button>
```

Comment: Please boil your question down to a single question. You don't want us to rewrite all your code, do you?

Comment: I might also worry about adding `include("conn.php");` into every function. You probably should add it once at the top of your script and inject the `$conn` as a parameter into each function to ensure you are not creating new connections each time one of those function is called.

Comment: Also, show your PDO attempt and what happened when it was executed (errors, etc.)

Comment: Sorry @KIKO Software i'm new here so i was having hard time posting questions and i dont want you to rewrite complete code i just want to understand how can i call a function made in pdo and replace mysqli_escape_string because my function is calling the store procedure

Comment: Hi @Rasclatt including it at once is a good idea and here is my attempt i.e failed attempt if(isset($_POST['search'])){
    $search=$_POST['search'];
    $query=$conn->prepare(GetWords($word));
    $query->execute(["%$search%"]);
    $count=$query->rowCount();
    if($count == 0){
            echo "sorry no results were found";
    } //here i'm trying to call GetWords Store Procedure however even my store procedure doesnt work take a look CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `GetWords`(IN pword varchar(200))
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM dictionarysearch where word like pword;
END

Comment: my error: fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Get::prepare() in C:\PHPP\htdocs\learnbootstrap\search.php:7 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\PHPP\htdocs\learnbootstrap\search.php